# Has There Been Any Study of the Quotient-root Derivative Definition $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sqrt[\Delta x]{\frac{f(x + \Delta x)}{f(x)}}$?

Tags: calculus, tetration, infinitesimals, hyperoperation

Has there been a study of turning the difference-quotient seen in the common derivative
$$
\frac d {dx} f(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} 
$$

into a quotient-root
$$
Д_x f(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sqrt[\Delta x]{\frac{f(x + \Delta x)}{f(x)}}?
$$

By approximating the function in Desmos, it seems that:
\begin{align}
Д_x C & = 1 \\
Д_x k f(x) & = Д_x f(x) \\
Д_x x^n & = e^\frac{n}{x} \\
Д_x a^x & = a \\
Д_x x^x & = ex
\end{align}

to list a few general functions.

Would such a definition allow for better definitions of hyperoperations like tetrations? Also, how would an integral calculus look with this as the basis? Are there any other types of derivatives out there like this? Can this be expressed with Leibniz notation?

Comment: What is the motivation for such a definition?

Comment: @NinadMunshi To be honest, curiosity mainly. Also, I was thinking that it could maybe relate higher operations such as tetration to other fundamental operations, like powers and multiplication.

Comment: I can be more specific - usually definitions are motivated by having special properties we are hunting for. Math education does math students a disservice by making it seem like definitions fell down from the sky with their properties derived later, when the math was always developed the other way around. For example, this definition does not lend itself to easy chaining or iteration. Does it agree with the regular derivative in specific cases you care about? Does it share some key property like a version of the product rule in a specific setting? Etc. Really any motivation helps.

Comment: This definition is equivalent to saying $$Д_x f(x) = \exp\left(\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)\right) = \exp\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)$$ in other words, a mapping of the logarithmic derivative of a function.

Comment: @WilliamRyman For positive valued functions $\,\ln Д_x f(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,$ is the [logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. They are extremely helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$y=\left(\frac{f(x+\epsilon )}{f(x)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\epsilon }}$$

Take logarithms, expand $f(x+\epsilon)$ as a series around $\epsilon=0$ to obtain
$$\log(y)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{  f(x) f''(x)-f'(x)^2}{2
   f(x)^2}\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ which makes the limit to be
$$y=\exp\Bigg[\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \Bigg]$$