# Is There a Finite Ratio Operator $_2\Delta$ so that $_2\Delta_n f(n) = \frac{f(n + 1)}{f(n)}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus, umbral-calculus

In mathematics, there is a finite difference operator $\Delta$ defined by $\Delta_n f(n) = f(n + 1) - f(n)$. This operator shares many properties with the continuous derivative $\mathcal{D}$. However, it lacks a simple composition relation. This operator finds use in calculating sums, demonstrated by the relation:
$$
\sum_{n = a}^{b - 1} \Delta_n f(n) = f(b) - f(a).
$$

My question is why isn't there an operator $_2\Delta$ defined as $_2 \Delta_n f(n) = \frac{f(n + 1)}{f(n)}$? This operator would be called the finite ratio operator. It is related to the variadic product operator $\prod$ given this relation:
$$
\prod_{n = a}^{b - 1} {_2\Delta_n} f(n) = \frac{f(b)}{f(a)}.
$$

This operator seems at the very least fairly useful for computing products, but I think it would also allow for an extension of the Umbral Calculus. I'm not quite sure how this extension would work (mainly because I don't quite know what an analogous ratio continuous derivative ($_2\mathcal{D}$) would look like, but I have [some thoughts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497766/has-there-been-any-study-of-the-quotient-root-derivative-definition-lim-delt)).

With the normal Umbral Calculus (at least according to my current understanding of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0EUFP7-P1M)), one is better able to transition between the discrete world of mathematics and the continuous world. This is done by introducing an operator $\phi$ so that $\Delta\phi = \mathcal{D}\phi$. I was thinking about introducing another operator $_2\phi$ where $_2\Delta_2\phi = {_2\phi}{_2\mathcal{D}}$, an operator $\alpha$ that relates $\Delta$ and $_2\Delta$, and an operator $\alpha'$ that relates $\mathcal{D}$ and $_2\mathcal{D}$.

The $_2\Delta$ could be generalized as $_n\Delta$, representing the "hyper-ratios" of higher hyperoperations.

Does such an operator like $_2\Delta$ already exist? If so, what has it been used for?

Comment: You are certainly free to define ${}_2\Delta$ with that formula? But I guess "does it already exist" is asking if someone else has already studied it?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes. I am particularly interested in if $_2\Delta$ has been studied and if so, what for.

Comment: It certainly exists in the form of $\exp \Delta \log$, just like its continuous counterpart $\exp D \log$ (as mentioned in [Claude Leibovici's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4497775) to your other question), so they are fairly closely related to their additive versions.